# Concat two arrays based on index

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to have the solution through *Linq* or lamda expression.

Can be done easily by looping but i wanted to try that in Linq or lambda expression.

```
string[] value1 = {"A", "B"};
string[] value2 = {"C", "D"};
```

or

```
List<string> value1 = new List<string>() {"A", "B"};
List<string> value2 = new List<string>() {"C", "D"};

var output = {"AC", "BD"};
```

concatinating the indexes

```
var output = {"AC","BD"};
```

Comment: If arrays have equal lengths:
`var output = value1.Zip(value2, (v1, v2) => v1 + v2).ToArray();`

Answer (score 3):

If arrays have *equal* lengths, put `Zip`:

```
var output = value1
  .Zip(value2, (v1, v2) => v1 + v2)
  .ToArray();
```

If not and we want to treat abscent items as empty strings:

```
var output = Enumerable
  .Range(0, Math.Max(value1.Length, value2.Length))
  .Select(i => (i < value1.Length ? value1[i] : "") + 
               (i < value2.Length ? value2[i] : ""))
  .ToArray();
```